# What can make DHCP fail?

Tags: networking, dhcp

I have (among other network devices) a RPi

```
Linux rpi2 4.1.10+ #821 PREEMPT Sat Oct 10 00:12:23 BST 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

It is connected via WiFi to an access point (like the other devices). A **static** network configuration works (connection to the AP and TCP/IP traffic).

I now wanted to move it to DHCP by modifying in `/etc/network/interfaces` the `wlan0` stanza from

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
        address 10.10.10.5
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 10.10.10.254
        wpa-essid "MYSSID"
        wpa-psk "mypassword"
```

to

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-essid "MYSSID"
        wpa-psk "mypassword"
```

The interface connects to the AP (which is visible though `iwconfig`) but does not get any IP.

- No request is visible on the server (which runs `dnsmasq` so I can se all the logs - which include the ones from other devices).
- other devices on the same AP get addresses without problems
- a `tcpdump` does not show any DHCP requests

**What could block the RPi to *request* an IP address?**

---

**Answer** (summarizing the answer to the question and my further comments): the lack of a client (which I must have removed when reconfiguring the device many times). Installing `isc-dhcp-client` fixed the issue.

Comment: You made a comment in response to my comment on the Answer. Yes the 1st will work. Static address will be allocated, but `dhcpcd` will still run, and allocate IP address from the DHCP server, the result being indeterminate. The second will not run `dhcpcd` (it will in fact but on detecting DHCP will disable itself as you would see from the logs). Neither is the recommended was of starting a WiFi network.

Comment: I am not sure I understand *"`dhcpcd` will still run, and allocate IP address from the DHCP server"* -- to which interface? If an interface is declared as static it will not have a DHCP client run against it (whether this is `dhcpcd` or `dhclient`). As for the second - it does run the DHCP client as I am getting IP addresses from my DHCP server (as soon as I installed the client which was, as I mentioned, missing). maybe it would be worthwhile to make an answer with the correct way to configure wifi - I would be glad to switch to the right one.

Comment: I gather from your posts that your Raspbian has been "hacked" so it is difficult to know exactly what it has. See my tutorial [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697). To attempt to answer setting static in `/etc/network/interfaces` doesn't work in current Raspbian - the Foundation even includes a comment in the latest versions of the file. `dhcpcd` allocates IP addresses for ALL interfaces it can find.

Comment: @Milliways: this is a very interesting link, thank you. And yet another approach to WiFi configuration (a well articulated on). Beside the `man` pages, is there a Debian/Ubuntu official doc pointing to this approach?

Comment: This is a Raspbian initiative not mainstream Debian/Ubuntu although it is used by many other distributions. The tutorial includes the links I found useful (ArchLinux particularly) as a result of a lot of research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to execute `/sbin/dhclient wlan0` *after* connecting in `post-up` or `up` script in `/etc/network/interfaces` and you better allow hotplug for wlan0

Comment: While it was not the exact reason,  your answer pointed me to the right direction. I discovered that there was no dhcp client installed at all. Installing it fixed the issue without any changes. Thanks.

Comment: @WoJ you're welcome! But one thing is concerning me - as I downloaded Raspbian Jessie from an official sources and installed it, `dhclient` was on board out-of-the-box...

Comment: Yes, you are right, this is the case for fresh installs. In the case of this particular RPi there is a long story of hacking around and it was on a static address before. I must have removed the dhcp client at some point. Another install on another RPi yesterday indeed had the client by default.

Comment: This is a collection of misinformation. All recent Raspbian run `dhcpcd` by default which (among other things0 acts as a DHCP client), although if you disable it `dhcpd` should work. Neither of the configurations  in the question would work (for different reasons).

Comment: @Milliways don't mess up a client(`dhclient`) and a server(`dhcpd`)

Comment: @Milliways: and yet, they do. The static one was working without problems (no DHCP involved) and the second one started when I re-installed the DHCP client. Where is the misinformation?